# Is it possible for the gains line to fall below the naive rule in a lift chart?

Tags: naive-bayes

I created a naive Bayes model  and generated this lift chart . Is it possible that my model could underperform the naiveBayes rule?

[image]

Comment: Looks like your model is actually working against you. If the model is binary, try flipping the sign of the prediction.

Comment: Thanks Demetri - sign flipping didn't change it.  My model accuracy with the holdout beats the naive rule.  Could this lift chart be telling that my model is not effective if the goal is ranking, even if accuracy metrics suggest the model is effective for prediction?

Comment: Could you post some sample data and the code used to produce this plot?